# flink on yarn - Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I'm trying to run a Flink job on yarn:

```
$ export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
$ ./${FLINK_HOME}/bin/yarn-session.sh ...
$ ./${FLINK_HOME}/bin/flink run \
    /home/clsadmin/messagehub-to-s3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
    --kafka-brokers ${KAFKA_BROKERS} \
    ...
     --output-folder s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${S3_FOLDER}
```

The startup output shows the hadoop classpath getting added to flink:

`Using the result of 'hadoop classpath' to augment the Hadoop classpath: /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop/conf:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop/.//*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*::mysql-connector-java.jar:/home/common/lib/dataconnectorStocator/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/tez/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/tez/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/tez/conf`

However, the job fails to start:

```
01/29/2018 16:11:04 Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
01/29/2018 16:11:04 Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED
01/29/2018 16:11:04 Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING
01/29/2018 16:11:05 Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to RUNNING
01/29/2018 16:11:05 Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to FAILED
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.createHadoopFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:1196)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initFileSystem(BucketingSink.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.initializeState(BucketingSink.java:355)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeOperators(StreamTask.java:694)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:682)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, if I look at the classpath reported by Flink:

```
$ grep org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop/.//*
```

I can see the hadoop-aws.jar is on the classpath:

```
...
Binary file /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop/.//hadoop-aws-2.7.3.2.6.2.0-205.jar matches
Binary file /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop/.//hadoop-aws.jar matches
...
```

Investigating further I can see the class exists in the jar:

```
jar -tf /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar | grep org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
```

returns

```
org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileSystem$1.class
org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileSystem$2.class
org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileSystem$3.class
org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileSystem$WriteOperationHelper.class
org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileSystem$4.class
org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileSystem.class
```

If I submit an example app:

```
./flink-1.4.0/bin/flink run \
   ./flink-1.4.0/examples/batch/WordCount.jar \
   --input "s3://${S3_BUCKET}/LICENSE-2.0.txt"  \
   --output "s3://${S3_BUCKET}/license-word-count.txt"
```

This runs without a problem.

My jar file doesn't contain any hadoop classes:

```
$ jar -tf /home/clsadmin/messagehub-to-s3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep hadoop
<<not found>>
```

Does any one have any idea why the Flink example runs ok, but Flink has an issue loading the S3AFileSystem with my code?

---

**Update:**

I fixed the problem by:

```
rm -f flink-1.4.0/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.4.0.jar
```

Is this a safe solution?

Comment: Chris did you solve this problem? how?